# runtime error 287 access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, ms-access-2016

This VBA work before we converted to Office 2016. I have 2 databases same VBA but stopping in to different places. I have tried replacing the 8G5DB with an email address but still does not work

```
Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("8G5DB")
```

one is stopping on first line and the other one is stopping on

```
Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("8G5DB")
```

This is my code:

```
Private Sub IRR_requested_AfterUpdate()
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient

Set dbs = CurrentDb
'  Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblCIPReqEmails")
'    rst.MoveFirst  

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With objOutlookMsg
    Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("8G5DB")
    objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo            

    .Subject = "IRR Requested"
    .Body = "SSN: " & Forms!frmAccession!SSN & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Employee Name: " & Forms!frmAccession![First Name] & " " & Forms!frmAccession![Middle Name] & " " & Forms!frmAccession![Last Name] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " IRR Requested: " & Forms!frmAccession![IRR requested] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "What Prior service is missing and dates of service" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Give OPF to Specialist" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Thank You." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    .Importance = olImportanceHigh       

    For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients
        objOutlookRecip.Resolve
        If Not objOutlookRecip.Resolve Then
        objOutlookMsg.Display
    End If
    Next
  '        .Send
    objOutlookMsg.Display

End With
Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Edit - from comments**

Following references are checked:

- Visual Basics for Applications;
- Microsoft Access 16.0 object library;
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Libary

Comment: not sure what you corrected I tried remving  what was in red still not working

Comment: the edit you rolled back was a formatting edit, not an answer

Comment: Does it give an error message when it stops?

Comment: same as before compile error User-defined type not defined

Comment: Can you check your references in the VB Editor and see if the current version of Outlook is checked? It looks like you're using an Outlook constant `olMailItem` - so you'd be getting an error if not using the Outlook Object Library - unless you're not using Option Explicit? I don't see it defined anywhere

Comment: I have the following references checked:

Comment: I have the following references checked: Visual Basics for Applications; Microsoft Access 16.0 object library; OLE Automation and Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Libary

Comment: Does the application compile? You are explicitly setting Outlook objects like  `Outlook.Application` - so to do it that way you need a reference to the Microsoft Outlook library. It should fail right now if you try to `Debug | Compile`

Comment: Before you add the recipient check to see if msg object has been created - `Debug.Print (objOutlookMsg Is Nothing)`

Comment: I do not know how to debug Compile?

Comment: I do not know how to debug.print

Comment: In your VB Editor, pull down menu `Debug` and click first line `"Compile <db name>"`

Comment: Use Ctrl-G to open the editor and immediate window. After line `Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)` insert line 
`Debug.Print (objOutlookMsg Is Nothing)` - show the results

Comment: it highlighted  this: Debug.Print (objOutlookMsg Is Nothing)

Comment: not sure I am putting in correct place

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need to do a bit more reading on basic VBA coding - especially on the troubleshooting and debugging die of things - every coder has to know how to step thru their lines and examine the content of variables to find a problem.

That being said, how about streamlining your test code to see if you can send an email, assuming you have no Outlook library referenced

```
    Private Sub IRR_requested_AfterUpdate()

        ' assume no references to Outlook
        ' Define Outlook constants to be used
        ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219371(v=office.11).aspx

        Const olTo             as Integer = 1
        Const olMailItem       As Integer = 0

        Dim objOutlook As Object
        Dim objOutlookMsg As Object
        Dim objOutlookRecip As Object

        '~~> Establish an Outlook application object if it is already open
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

        '~~> If not then, launch it
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        End If
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With objOutlookMsg
            Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("8G5DB")
            objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo            
            objOutlookRecip.Resolve

            .Subject = "IRR Requested"
            .Body = "SSN: Test"
            .Send
            .Display

        End With
        Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
        Set objOutlook = Nothing
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not recognizing your parameter for objOutlookMsg. try:

```
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
```

Also, make sure `Option Explicit` is at the top of your module.

Comment: getting Compile error: Invalid inside procedure     Private Sub IRR_requested_AfterUpdate() Option Explicit

Comment: I replace Private Sub with Option Explicit and now I am not getting a debug but also not getting an email to generate

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` before any code at the top of the doc.

Comment: `Option Explicit`
`Private Sub IRR_requested_AfterUpdate()`

Comment: it will not let me do this it gives me an error  Compile error: Expected: end of statement

Comment: Although it won't let me show it in the comment, `Option Explicit` and `Private Sub IRR_requested_AfterUpdate()` should be on different lines

Answer (score 0):

So...

In your question and comments you listed the following references on the database:

•Visual Basics for Applications;

•Microsoft Access 16.0 object library;

•OLE Automation

•Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Libary

As previously mentioned by @dbmitch, to run Outlook automation, you require a reference for `Microsoft Outlook XX.X Library`. If you add that, it may fix your issues. Microsoft Office Object Library does not cut it.

Comment: I only have: Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library; Microsoft Outlook SharePoint Social Provider; Microsoft Outlook Social Provider Extensibility & Microsoft Outlook View Control

Comment: Yes, `Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library` is correct. The XX.X stand for numbers that I don't know based on your version of Access. Hope this helps.

Comment: add the Microsoft outlook 16.0 library and it is now stopping on: Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipents.Add("8G5DB") tried changing 8G5DB to the email address for this number but still getting error on this line

Comment: What do you mean by "stopping"? Is it throwing some sort of error?

Comment: getting a debug runtime error 287 application defined or object-defined error when I click debug it highlights this Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipents.Add("8G5DB")